# sanitizing unsafe URL value in angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript

**app.component.ts**

```
 this.imageurl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,' 
 +this.basepath+this.employee.id+this.mainpath+ this.employee.profile);
```

**Html**

```
<img src="{{'data:image/jpg;base64,' + imageurl}}" width="200px" height="200px" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify like this

```
<img [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,' + imageurl" width="200px" height="200px" alt="" />
```